# Vue.js 2: Delete property from data object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How can you delete a property/key from a Vue.js data object (i.e. associative array) like this:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    data: {
        users: {
            foo : { firstName: ..., lastName: ... },
            bar : { firstName: ..., lastName: ... }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        someFunction : function ()
        {
            // how to remove `users.foo`?
        }
    }
});
```

Googling around, I found these two ways, but both don't work:

- `delete this.users.foo;` is not updating the DOM
- `this.users.splice('foo', 1);` is not working at all (probably only works on arrays, not on objects)

Comment: I believe vue2 implements its own splice for array. Wouldn't work on objects though, as you say.

Answer (score 184):

The answer is:

```
Vue.delete(users, 'foo');
```

It took me a while to find it, that's why I'm posting it here ;-)
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3368#issuecomment-236642919

Comment: Weirdly, it's not even described in the documentation: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats. It just says "Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion" and doesn't explain how you're supposed to do it

Comment: @Migwell it seems to be mentioned here: https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/

Comment: It's worth noting that if you want to *add* a property to an object, the analogue is `Vue.set`.

Answer (score 105):

It's important to know that `vm.$delete` is a alias for `Vue.delete` and if you try something like `this.delete()` you will get a error. So in your example the answer would be:

```
this.$delete(this.users, 'foo')
```

or

```
vm.$delete(vm.users, 'foo')
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#vm-delete-changed

Comment: Thank you very much.It's acutally a correct answer.    It can solve the VUEJS problem which cannot watch   data removed from or added to.

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a new copy of the object so Vue be able to know that there are changes:

**ES6**

```js
const users = { ...this.users };
delete users['foo'];
this.users = users
```

or **without spread operator** it would be

```js
const users = Object.assign({}, this.users);
delete users['foo'];
this.users = users
```

Comment: using `Vue.delete` is preferable to this solution since it doesn't involve creating a whole new object as it is done here