# Vue Keys do not delete from Object

Tags: vue.js, object, methods, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to delete a key from an object in a parent component. A child component emits an event (with an item value) back to the parent method that triggers the delete in the parent's data object.

Parent component:

```js
data() {
  return {
    savedNews: Object
  }
},
methods: {
  containsKey(obj, key) {
    var result = Object.keys(obj).includes(key)
    return result
  },
  handleSaveNews(item) {
    if (!this.containsKey(this.savedNews, item.url)) {
      this.savedNews = {
        [item.url]: item,
        ...this.savedNews
      }
    } else {
      console.log(this.containsKey(this.savedNews, item.url))
      var res = delete(this.savedNews, item.url)
      console.log(res)
      console.log(this.containsKey(this.savedNews, item.url))
    }
  }
}
```

All of the `console.log`s in the last else statement return true. It's saying that the delete was successful yet the key is still there. How do I delete this key?

Comment: Where does that `delete` function come from?

Comment: Your data should not be initialising `savedNews` to the `Object` constructor. Instead, try `savedNews: {}` or `savedNews: Object.create(null)`

Comment: I came upon `delete` via other posts. It's supposedly an ES6 method of doing it. Didn't work for me, though. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954459/vue-js-2-delete-property-from-data-object]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats):

> Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion

Use `this.$delete`:

```
this.$delete(this.savedNews, item.url)
```

or `this.$set` (which also should be used for property changes):

```
this.$set(this.savedNews, item.url, undefined);
```

---

**Extra info:**  The `$` is a naming convention Vue uses for its built-in methods that are available on each component instance.  There are some plugins which opt to follow this pattern too. You can also use built-ins inside other modules if you `import Vue` and use `Vue.delete`, for example.  You could add your own methods like `Vue.prototype.$mymethod = ...`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm fairly new to Vue. What is the usage behind `this.$<function_name>`? What does the `$` signify?

Comment: You're welcome!  The `$` is a naming convention Vue uses for its built-in methods that are available on each component instance.  You could add your own like `Vue.prototype.$mymethod`.  There are some plugins which opt to follow this pattern too.  You can also use built-ins inside other modules if you `import Vue` and use `Vue.delete` for example.  I'll copy this info to the answer.