# Trouble Removing Deep Object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, javascript-objects

I have a an object inside an object that is used by my Vue component to display an element. When I click a button on the page, I want to delete one of the nested objects. It seems to delete, when I do console.log(this.query_filters.target_filters[id]) immediately after deleting the element, it shows that the object is removed (see first screenshot). However, the Vue tab still shows the element, and my UI doesn't update to indicate that it was removed (see second screenshot).

I am deleting the nested object like this:
`delete this.query_filters.target_filters[id];`

I am not resetting/adding the object back anywhere else (this only happens once when a certain button is clicked).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

`Vue.delete(this.query_filters.target_filters, id);`

(Source: [Vue.js 2: Delete property from data object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954459/vue-js-2-delete-property-from-data-object))